# Catching a custom exception with cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, try-catch, cfml

How does one catch a custom exception with `try-catch` in cfscript?

```
<cffunction name="myFunction">
  <cfset foo = 1>

  <cfif foo EQ 1>
    <cfthrow type="customExcp" message="FAIL!">
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

The `try-catch` is in cfscript. What should go into the `catch()` statement?

```
try {
  myFunction();
} catch () {
  writeOutput("Ooops");
}
```

Comment: I don't know but the first thing I would try is "throw".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

James has pointed you to the docs in his answer, but he's missed the bit about you asking about *custom* exceptions. The syntax is:

```
try {
    myFunction();
} catch (customExcp e) {
    writeOutput("Ooops");
    writeDump(e); // have a look at the contents of this
}
```

Note you can have as many `catch` blocks as you like, for different exception types. Any exception type not explicitly caught will still be thrown.